# Xamarin installer fails to delete source directory on Windows

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

The problems in my log started with this:

```
[Exception] Failed to delete source directory '<USER_HOME>\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools' after copying it to '<USER_HOME>\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools.old464541238'
[Exception] System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'adb.exe' is denied.
[Exception] at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)
[Exception] at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)
[Exception] at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.MoveDirectory(String sourceDirName, String destDirName, Boolean move, Boolean overwrite, Boolean createSourceDirRootAtDestination)
```

Even though the Xamarin installer complained about a timeout, I figured that wasn't it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some googling, I found this [similar error](http://odedrabanitips.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/access-to-path-adbexe-is-denied-while.html), which occurred while trying to install Droid Explorer, but it turns out we had the same problem and solution: **if `adb.exe` is running, you must kill its process before proceeding with the installation**.

This looks like it wouldn't happen on a system without any prior Android SDK installation (or even if `adb.exe` isn't running), but as I think it's common for people with Android development experience to try out Xamarin.Android, it could help other people with similar issues.

Comment: `abd.exe` was running.  killed it, then the install (repair) completed successfully.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, with Visual Studio 2022, the adb.exe process was not running but I was still getting the error. The solution was to find the SDK Manager .exe file (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\AndroidSdkManager) and manually run that as an Administrator. I was then able to run the SDK repair process, after-which it has been working fine in Visual Studio.